# How do I know if my MySQL Database has a password?

Tags: mysql, excel

Is there a way to know if my MySQL Database has a password? As far as I remember, I haven't set a Password.

I need the following things -

```
SERVER=127.0.0.1 (I know)
DATABASE= Confused Between MySQL Connections & Schema. Which one if these two? 
UID= Where can I find this? 
PWD= need to know if my MySQL Database has a password?
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Connect to your system administrator to get this information. There can be a lot of different configuration options depending on your mysql installation so you should contact to system administrator to get your connection details.

Comment: Well unfortunately, I have installed it myself. I am just trying to connect a Excel Userform to have the data update in the database.

Comment: Default UID: "root" in that case. it also asks you to define a password while installing so this may vary but if you just skipped it than default password is empty ( "" ). If you are connecting from your local machine try connecting 127.0.0.1 or if you want a faster connection( A socket connection instead of tcp) localhost instead. Localhost may not always work depending of your installation. DATABASE also may vary because you suppose to create one and name it.

Comment: Thank you for the revert. I somehow sorted out the problem.